# Where does my devops question belong to?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've just filed a somewhat broad question on superuser and received feedback saying I was posting off-topic in this forum. Hence my meta question, where would this very question fit in best?

The question:

[How to emulate a private IP address for local Apache webserver?](https://superuser.com/questions/1030659/how-to-emulate-a-private-ip-address-for-local-apache-webserver)

- stackexchange?
- serverfault?
- ProWebmasters?
- WordPress?
- ...?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if anyone had complained about your question if it didn't contain "Wordpress". To me, that question could be best posted on the dedicated WordPress site, or ServerFault if the question is not WordPress specific.

To me the sentence "How do I do X in Apache" says to me it is a system administrators job, the typical users of Apache. But a high-reputation user on SU indicated the question is off-topic on Super User, which makes me wonder if it is well-received on SF. Maybe I just don't have enough experience there.

The WordPress site might be the right site. And guess what, they even have an [apache tag](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache), with similar questions like you have. From my point-of-view, that is most likely the site to ask.

Comment: Raises hand. I am the high rep user mentioned (it doesn't mean I'm always correct though). In this particular case it **seems** to be a wordpress specific problem hence the advice to post over there.

Comment: I appreciate your opinion and thanks for the comment. I don't have much experience on SU, so I think you are a better judge on that than I am. Wordpress.SE doesn't seem the wrong place either way.

Comment: I appreciate your comments and answers. However, I'm still in doubt whether this is really a WordPress question in the first place. To me, it is more a devops question relating to distributed version management, local Apache settings (note: far from _professional server environments_ as required at SF ...)

Comment: That is my thought too, maybe David is wrong :)

Comment: The more I think about, the more I'm getting convinced that my question is mostly Apache2 web server related. When browsing the help sections of the mentioned platforms, I'm more and more starting to believe that SF ist the right place to go for. Think, I'll try it there. Maybe, we see back here later... ;)
Anyway, thanks guys!

Comment: You are welcome. Please let us know how it ended.

Comment: @Bunjip Hmm. The only answer to your question so far suggests a change to your WordPress site configuration ...

Comment: @DavidPostill that doesn't make it off-topic. A single suggesting (low-quality answer) isn't really an answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill, you are right as far as that one WordPress concerns. However, the core of my question relates way more to dev environment topics, I think

Comment: Question refined and posted to SF: http://serverfault.com/questions/751583/how-to-set-up-apache2-on-different-local-development-environments-to-use-the-sam